# Kotlin JOOQ fetch data and then map static data afterwards

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, jooq

It is possible to map static properties after selecting data from DB?
For example if I want that result of some field will be always `ENUM_VALUE`. I will add an example to make myself more clear.

Target dto I want to fill via JOOQ

```
internal data class MytargetClass(val property: Int, val static_value: MyEnum)
```

Since static_value is val and its not optional, I need to initialize that property while creating object. So way to create object only with `property` and map `static_value` afterwards is not possible.

This is a solution that works, I add my enum value as string via `val` method, but this approach is not really something that I would want.

```
// Repository file, other fields and method omitted for simplicity        
        jooq
        .select(
            t.property.`as`("property"),
            DSL.`val`(Enum.MY_VALUE.name).`as`("static_value"),
        )
        // from and where clause omitted for simplicity
        .fetchInto(MytargetClass::class.java)
```

**But I would like to ask if there is way how to do something like**

```
// Repository file, other fields and method omitted for simplicity   
    jooq
    .select(
        t.property.`as`("property"),
    )
    // from and where clause omitted for simplicity
    .fetchInto(MytargetClass::class.java, (data) -> { data.static_value = Enum.MY_VALUE // possible more transformation of object inside this lambda })
```

So I dont have to select these properties statically via SQL and therefore I can bypass problems with ENUM dialects and other issues linked to this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using `DefaultRecordMapper`

Just use a custom `RecordMapper` via [`ResultQuery.fetch(RecordMapper)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetch(org.jooq.RecordMapper)) and call [`apply`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html) on a mapped value

```kotlin
.fetch {
    it.into(MytargetClass::class.java).apply { 
        static_value = Enum.MY_VALUE
    }
}
```

### Using any other `RecordMapper`

The above just assumes you want to continue using the `DefaultRecordMapper`, which is reflection based. But you don't have to. You can do anything you want with `it`:

```kotlin
.fetch {
    MytargetClass(it[t.property], Enum.MY_VALUE)
}
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this does not seem to work. I am getting error of setting null value to not nullable field (static enum field). To under the hood it probably tries to create object first (with null field) and enhance it with data, which is approach I can not use due to not nullable field.

Comment: @Johnczek: Well, apparently, you cannot use `DefaultRecordMapper`, but what keeps you from implementing any other explicit function? A `RecordMapper` is just a function. You can implement it in any way you want. I've updated my answer to give you an idea.

Comment: yea, I thought is may end up like this, writing custom fetch filling function (which I, at the end, ended with), its a pity there is no automatic way to achieve what I need integrated inside JOOQ. But thanks for help

Comment: @Johnczek: I'm not sure what you mean by "inside of jOOQ". The constructor call is an atomic operation, and all data points need to be non-null as per your class requirements. How could jOOQ prevent any NPE?

Comment: I was hoping for some "under the hood" layer that JOOQ (for simplicity just imagine its a "dumb" map that holds key pointing to name of result object and holding result of SQL) and then some function I can specify overrides (or additions) for that SQL result. And just at this point, the contructor of desired object would be called with these data.